# PHP 3 dropdown menu populated 3times by a foreach loop

Tags: php, html

Im from Germany and my english is not perfect but i will try my best to explain the problem that i have.

i have a html table and i created each tablerow and his tabledata in a foreach loop. I have two dropdown menues in the table and each of them are populated with another foreach loop. My Problem is: I Try to echo all the values from the dropdown menues after submit the form and i can display only the productnumber and productname correctly but the values from the dropdown menues are not correctly showed.

Here the code:

```
foreach ($produktdaten['products'] as $output){
echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="opproduktnummer" value="' . $output['id'] . '">' . $output['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="opproduktname" value="' . $output['name'] . '">' . $output['name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><select name="opproduktccp">';
        foreach ($op_options['ccp'] as $opccp) {
          echo '<option>'.$opccp.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></td>';
        echo '<td><select name="opproduktlevel">';
          foreach ($levelarray["mlevels"] as $key){
            echo "<option>" . $key . "</option>";
          }
        echo '</select></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="submit" name="save_data" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Speichern"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
            if( isset( $_POST['save_data'] ) ){
      echo $keys;
      echo "<br>";
      echo $values;
}
```

In my first array $produktdaten['products'] i have three products with different values. I need only the produktid and his name. This is why i choose $output['id'] and $output['name']. and this is working. 
[THIS IS THE TABLE right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXvH7.png)

Each dropdown menue is showing correctly with his options for each row.
As i said when i submit the form i need to grab each option that the user is choosen. But i get as result only the last option in the dropdown menu for each row. 
[THIS IS an EXAMPLE WHEN WE CHOOSE something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHPxA.png)

When i submit i get this-> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNKTq.png)

I need for each productid and his name the right value that the user is choosing in the dropdown menues. Please help me because i try different methods more then two weeks now. Im new in PHP (3month working with it).
I hope that someone here can help me because i learned a lot from this forum. Greez from Germany.

Comment: Can you please show us the structure of the array? Using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`

Comment: Array ( [1] => digiempire_advanced [2] => digiempire_pro [3] => digiempire_basic ) This is from print_r($op_options['ccp']); the other one $produktdaten['products'] is too long for comment. Thank you for you fast answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the latest values because every select you use has the same name.

Ie. you have three of "opproduktccp" and three of "opproduktlevel", so the latest value the forms sends "overrides" the previous ones.

If you want each value separately you either have to:
A) name the select differently, ie "opproduktlevel1", "opproduktlevel2", etc.
or
B) make them an array, ie. "opproduktlevel[]" or, preferably, number them "opproduktlevel[1]", etc

B) solution is the one you want if you have differing number of possible products (you don't know if you'll have 2 or 4, for example).

With B you can then take the arrays and loop through each one. *Or* better yet if you have numbered them, you can foreach through opproduktlevel and take the key value and use it as the key for opproduktccp, or vice versa.

So, assuming your $output['id'] is unique, your code could be something like:

```
        foreach ($produktdaten['products'] as $output){
    echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="opproduktnummer" value="' . $output['id'] . '">' . $output['id'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="opproduktname" value="' . $output['name'] . '">' . $output['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><select name="opproduktccp['.$output['id'].']">';
            foreach ($op_options['ccp'] as $opccp) {
              echo '<option>'.$opccp.'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select></td>';
            echo '<td><select name="opproduktlevel['.$output['id'].']">';
              foreach ($levelarray["mlevels"] as $key){
                echo "<option>" . $key . "</option>";
              }
        echo '</select></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="submit" name="save_data" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Speichern"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
            if( isset( $_POST['save_data'] ) ){
      echo $keys;
      echo "<br>";
      echo $values;
}
```

After form submission you should have two arrays with the user selections, which you can loop through.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. I will try now your solution. i replace my code with yours and i get the two arrays. i will try now to var_dump this two and after that i will loop through...i give my feedback

Comment: Hi, can you give me an example how to foreach now through the arrays.

Comment: i dont need it anymore. sorry for the question. if the topic is solved it can be closed this post. Thank you again for the help!